# How to delete matching rows/records between tables using Access VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to delete all rows (records) from a table (Table2) that appear in another table (Table3) that have the same Code (present on Column "Code", with the same name for both tables).

I found a suggested solution in SQL:

```
DELETE Table2
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.Code = Table3.Code
```

My try in Access VBA.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 on Table2.Code = Table3.Code"
```

I get

> runtime error "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete"

What I got partially working:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Table2 WHERE Table3.Code = Table3.Code"
```

This second code opens a popup asking for a parameter (what I want to match), which works, but I want to do that inputless.

---

Solution:

Adapting the code Doug Coats provided and "adapting" for Access VBA:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Table2 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Table3.Code FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Code = Table2.Code )"
DoCmd.Requery
```

Added `.Requery` to remove the #Deleted that comes when deleting the records.

Comment: `WHERE Table3.Code = Table3.Code` any survivors?

Comment: Didn't understand the question greybeard

Comment: I can't imagine any record where `Table3.Code` does *not* equal `Table3.Code`, and this condition is presented in a `DELETE * FROM Table2` as `partially working`: did any record survive this attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im generally not a fan of joining to a table just to check for the existence of some value.

Try using this instead:

```
    DELETE 
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT t3.Code 
            FROM Table3 t3 
            WHERE t3.Code = t2.Code
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, got the code to work, only had to adapt for VBA as I have little knowledge. I'll be editing the question with the working code!